# Using automatic setting but getting wrong timezone (missing 30 minutes)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, internationalization, timezone

Malaysia timezone supposed to be GMT +8:00

But in my macbook (OS 10.13.5) it displays GMT +7:30 (note the last picture, bottom right), 30 minutes was missing, how can i fix this?

Note: I tried to set it manually via select the location /closest city, it still giving me GMT +7:30

It is giving me the wrong time display on some of the website now. For example, 9:00am become 8:30am

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wow. That looks like a bug that Apple could verify and fix if you filed one. If you’re a developer, use the bug reporter. If not, calling AppleCare and asking them to help you set up the proper time zone, and if they fail, pointing them to this excellent documentation of how you sure look to me did everything correctly.

Worst case, they explain the fix and you can post an answer here for all to learn.

Comment: Hmm. I would like to see if this is an issue with the device or with, as you said, an Apple Bug. Unfortunately, I'm not in Malaysia, so I'll have to spoof my location.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i've logged a report to Apple, but does not getting any reply yet :( By the way, my friend mbp has similar issue too.

Comment: It would be 1 million to one odds you'll ever get a direct response other than perhaps a request for more data or log files. But, maybe yours is the lottery ticket that wins?

Comment: it has been days and i still get 0 comment from the ticket. This is the portal im using to report https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: @ChinKang Yes - unless you want to pay Apple for specific incident, you'll likely want to wait 6 months before you expect even a close as dupe if they are tracking it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer via the other question, it is due to the Malaysia's [time history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Malaysia), and it may not related to any OS timezone issue.

The last screenshot above may be is just showing some example values.

The fact is that, Malaysia used to be having timezone of GMT+7:30.

Therefore in the website which **parsing the datetime prior to year 1982**, will display the time in GMT+7:30, and on or after the first day of 1982, it will display the time in GMT+8:00.

[image]